# Loop to create multiple sheets in multiple Excel workbooks

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, lapply, r-xlsx

I have a dataset with two different groups and their values, something like this:

```
example <- data.frame('Group' = c('building 1', 'building 1', 
                                  'building 2', 'building 2'),
                      'Subgroup' = c('Active','Inactive','Active','Inactive'),
                      'Value' = c('abc','def','ghi','jkl'))
```

I know I can use lapply to output a workbook for each 'building':

```
buildings <- split(example, example$Group)

lapply(1:length(buildings), 
        function(x) write.xlsx(buildings[[x]], 
                               file = paste0(names(buildings[x]), '.xlsx'), 
                               row.names = FALSE))
```

Similarly, here would be the code to create multiple sheets within 1 workbook based on a column:

```
activity <- split(example, example$Subgroup)

lapply(1:length(activity), 
        function(x) write.xlsx(activity[[x]], file = 'All values.xlsx',
                               sheetName = paste0(names(activity[x])), 
                               append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE))
```

My question is, is there a way in R where these can these be combined (or is there another way) to create separate Workbooks by Group, with multiple sheets by Subgroup? What I'd want is a file for Building 1 that has 2 sheets: Active and Inactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modify your code as follows. Since `openxlsx::write.xlsx()` will automatically use the name of the named list, such as `activity`, as the name of the sheets. The only thing you have to do is split the `buildings` in the `lapply()` function.

```
example <- data.frame('Group' = c('building 1', 'building 1', 'building 2', 'building 2'),
                      'Subgroup' = c('Active','Inactive','Active','Inactive'),
                      'Value' = c('abc','def','ghi','jkl'))


buildings <- split(example, example$Group)

lapply(seq_along(buildings), 
       function(x) {
         activity <- split(buildings[[x]], buildings[[x]]$Subgroup)
         openxlsx::write.xlsx(
           activity,
           file = paste0(names(buildings[x]), '.xlsx'),
           row.names = FALSE
         )
       })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the data into nested lists which first level is split by `Group` and the second level is by `Subgroup`. Then you can write them into workbooks with separate sheets in a loop. See below;

```r
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)

example %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
  split(., .$Group) %>% 
  lapply(., function(x) split(x, x$Subgroup)) %>% 
  lapply(., function(dat) 
    lapply(dat, function(dat.sub) 
      write.xlsx(dat.sub, 
                 file = paste0(as.character(unique(dat.sub$Group)), ".xlsx"),
                 sheetName = paste0(as.character(unique(dat.sub$Subgroup))), 
                 append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)))
```

Comment: With the current version of `dplyr`, it would be `mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character))`

Comment: @akrun I haven't read the update log yet, you mean `mutate_...` are deprecated?

Comment: It will be deprecated in the future.  Now, it is all in `mutate` with `across`